# Pass tokens/query string through url once the user hits a redirect

Tags: php

I have a url that a visitor is on, this URL contains various tokens.

ex. `mydomain.comm/stuff.php?c=adfads&age=24&type=male&location=canada`

This person gets redirected to the URL with JavaScript that successfully forwards the tokens into the URL.

The PHP script is a header redirect. Ex.:

```
<?php

header( "Location: mydomain.com" ) ;

?>
```

When the person goes through the redirect, the tokens are lost. They are not placed on the redirect URL.

How do I ensure the tokens get appended to the end of the url?

Comment: What is your specific question here? How to retrieve the query string parameters? How to concatenate a string? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

you could always grab the varibles and place them back in the URL

```
<?php
$c = $_GET['c'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$location = $_GET['location'];

header( "Location: mydomain.com?". $c . "&" . $age . "&" . $type . "&" . $location ) ;

?>
```